# How to get mean + standard deviation into a single column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Hi guys is it possible to get mean and standard deviation into a single column?

for example if i had the following code;

```
data %>% 
select(age, gender) %>% 
group_by(gender) %>% 
summarise(mean.age = mean(age), sd.age = sd(age)
```

this would display a tibble with mean age and standard deviation for each gender as 2 separate column.

how do i get this to display as one column so the format is like "age = 18 ± 2"?

Answer (score 2):

You can paste the two values together.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  group_by(gender) %>% 
  summarise(age = paste(round(mean(age),2), round(sd(age),2) sep = ' ± '))
```

For eg with `mtcars` data -

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise(age = paste(round(mean(mpg), 2), round(sd(mpg), 2), sep = ' ± '))

#    cyl age         
#  <dbl> <chr>       
#1     4 26.66 ± 4.51
#2     6 19.74 ± 1.45
#3     8 15.1 ± 2.56
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `glue`

```
library(dplyr)
library(glue)
data %>%
    group_by(gender) %>%
    summarise(age = glue('{round(mean(age), 2)} ± {round(sd(age), 2)}')
```

---

A reproducible example with `mtcars`

```
mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    summarise(age = glue('{round(mean(mpg), 2)} ± {round(sd(mpg), 2)}'))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
    cyl age         
  <dbl> <glue>      
1     4 26.66 ± 4.51
2     6 19.74 ± 1.45
3     8 15.1 ± 2.56
```